# import image in css file for react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

i am trying to use an image from public/assets/subtract.png  and it can t be resolved

This is the :

```
body {
  background-image: url("./assets/subtract.png");
}
```

The problem is this :

```
./src/styles/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles/index.css)
Error: Can't resolve './assets/subtract.png' in 'E:\xampp\htdocs\learning\my-app\src\styles'
```

even if i tried to put it in the puplic folder not in inside assets its give me error

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Can't resolve './assets/subtract.png' in 'E:\xampp\htdocs\learning\my-app\src\styles'
```

As you can see in this error the css tries to acces the image in /src/styles/assets/subtract.png and I would assume, that your picture is actually in /assets/subtract.png
so try this instead:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/assets/subtract.png");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the file path carefully and again remap the path according to the file location.